# How to Maintain Eyetracking Calibration Across Multiple Webpages in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, eye-tracking

I'm engaged in a project centered around the question: "Is it possible to translate eye movements and blinking, facilitated by a Chrome extension, into meaningful website interactions?"

The primary objective is to achieve seamless scrolling based on gaze direction and enable clicking through blinking. Currently, I've implemented this functionality by injecting an eyetracking script (specifically, GazeCloudAPI) into the active webpage upon opening the Chrome extension.

While this setup works seamlessly within a single webpage, a challenge arises when navigating to a new webpage through a link click. The eyetracking script gets reinjected into the page, necessitating recalibration each time.

Considering the limitations, I'm exploring potential workarounds to maintain eyetracking calibration across multiple webpages. Is there a method to preserve calibration data or any other approach to overcome this challenge?